# if not exist folder stored in variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have tried adding quotes, echoing instead of making a directory. I cannot get the if statement to use the variable as a directory path. What can I do?

```
SET reportdir=C:\DBMSDBII\Reports\

IF NOT EXIST %reportdir% MKDIR %reportdir%
```

Comment: Works perfectly happily for me. Perhaps you've pruned you code excessively - is this actually within a loop, for instance?

Comment: A simple way to do make a directory if it doesn't exist is to just make the the directory and ignore the error if it already exists: `mkdir %reportdir% 2> NUL`